# What story and one-digit Natural Numbers best fit Bayes' Theorem chart?

Tags: probability

Some students have sniveled that most examples of Bayes' Theorem use non-integer numbers. I want to try a Bayes' Theorem chart that uses just single digit Natural Numbers $\le 9$. To complete the table below most comfortably for teenagers,

1. what are the simplest stories?
2. what natural numbers ≤ 9 contrast the base rate fallacy the most? Please don't repeat a number.

[The biggest number in this similar question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/16977/15364) still uses two digits, and rehashes the common example of letting D be be a disease and $H_0$ be a negative (diagnostic) test result. What other $H_0, D$ are more intuitive?   Green denotes true positive and negative, red false positive and negative.

$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
\text{Number of occurrences}&D &\lnot D  &\text{Total}\\ \hline
H_a &\color{green}{\Pr(D)\Pr(+|D)}&\color{red}{\Pr(D^C)\Pr(+|D^C)}&\text{add the 2 left entries}\\
H_0 &\color{red}{\Pr(D)\Pr(-|D)}&\color{green}{\Pr(D^C)\Pr(-|D^C)}&\text{add the 2 left entries}\\ \hline
\text{Total}&\text{add the 2 above entries}&\text{add the 2 above entries}&\text{single digit integer}
\end{array}$

Comment: Asked again at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4002549/18398

Answer (score 6):

> Two professional athletes and six fans are eating at a restaurant table.  Both of the professional athletes are wearing their jerseys, while only half of the fans are wearing jerseys.  Given a person at the table wearing a jersey, what is the probability that they are a professional athlete?

I don't know why you think that students understand BT better with single-digit numbers.  Seems to me that with a hundred fans it becomes far clearer how unlikely it is that a jersey-wearing person is an athlete even though all of the athletes are wearing jerseys.  But you do you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Students still can't intuit Bayes's Theorem! " If you keep doing the same thing, you'll get the same results."  I just want to try something else